# Need help to write doxygen comments for javascript module

Tags: javascript, doxygen

I am new to Doxygen and need help to understand generating document of following code with details of init() and showSpinner()

Thanks in advance for this help

---

```
var myNamespace = {};
myNamespace.Global = (function () {
    var initFlag = true, $ = "";
    function init(reinit) {
        if (initFlag || reinit) {
           initFlag = false;
        }
    }
    function showSpinner() {
        $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
    }
    return {
        init: init,
        showSpinner: showSpinner
    };
 }());
```

Comment: Did you try searching for a tutorial about using Doxygen on Javascript? (http://coherent-labs.com/blog/documenting-javascript-with-doxygen/)  Right now this question is probably "too broad" as it appears to be simply asking us to teach you Doxygen.

Answer (score -1):

I got answer from following link
http://devnull.absolventa.de/2014/03/25/jsdoc-and-the-revealing-module-pattern/

Its working.

Also instead of doxygen, i used jsdocs which is pretty easy.